# A problem of uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider two Hilbert spaces $X,Y$, and a family of linear bounded operators $R_t: Y\rightarrow X$, $t>0$. Let also be $D$ a linear, non closed dense subspace of $Y$, and $P$ a linear discontinuous operator $D \rightarrow X$.

> Under the assumption that, for every $g\in D$, $R_tg \rightarrow Pg$ for $t\rightarrow 0$, can we conclude that there is $g \in Y$ with $||R_t g ||\rightarrow +\infty$?

Here is a first try: I show at first that $||R_t||\rightarrow \infty$ for $t\rightarrow 0$. Indeed, suppose we find $0<t_n\rightarrow_n0$ with $||R_{t_n}||$ bounded. Then, $R_{t_n}$ converge pointwise on a dense subspace of $Y$, $R_{t_n}$ are uniformly bounded $\implies$ $R_{t_n}$ converge pointwise on all of $Y$ by Banach-Steinhaus, so that the limit is a bounded operator $T: Y\rightarrow X$, with $T|_D=P$. This contradicts the non-continuity of $P$.

Now I would like to show my claim, but here I'm stuck, I feel I cannot find a clever enough way to apply uniform boundedness. What I got is: find $0<t_n\rightarrow_n0$ with  $\sup_n ||R_{t_n}|| = \infty$. Then, by the uniform boundedness principle, there is $g \in Y$ with $\sup_n ||R_{t_n}g||=\infty$, and we can thus conclude $||R_{t_n}g||\rightarrow_n\infty$.

But how about every other sequence $0<s_n\rightarrow_n0$?

---

*Context*

I'm particularly interested in the case where $P=A^+$, the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A\in L(X,Y)$, so that $D = ran A \oplus ran A ^\perp$. This result would then show that linear regularizations alone, are not sufficient to tackle the ill-posedness of the operator equation $Af=g$. The result becomes true if one for instance supposes $AR_t$ uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 1):

If $R_t g$ has a finite limit for all $g \in Y$, then the uniform boundedness theorem tells you that operator $$Qg = \lim_{t \to \infty} R_tg$$ is bounded since it is a pointwise limit of bounded operators (one does not require a uniform bound on the operator norms of $R_t$ here as an assumption; in fact, it follows from the UBT).

Then $P$ has a bounded extension which seems to contradict your assumption (though I'd note that in the usual terminology unbounded operators may actually be bounded, but from your attempt it seems this is not what you mean).

Comment: Right, we must conclude that $R_t g$ doesn't have a finite limit for all $g \in Y$, otherwise, as you say, we get a contradiction. Does it mean that for a $g$, $\lim_t R_t g = \infty$?

Comment: @warm_fish $R_t g$ is an element of a Hilbert space, so $\lim_t R_t g=\infty$ doesn't make any immediate sense. Do you mean $\lim_t \lVert R_t g\rVert=\infty$?

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, exactly!